# Background does not apply for h1 and floated image

Tags: css

I have floated the image left with a class of logo. I apply a background color for `h1` and the image but it does not appear for some reason. Why is this happening? I have floated the image because the text appears below the image not top of the image. Is there a way to deal with it?

JS Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/z8cw31j9/

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Niconne);
 body {
    background: #e6e3d7;
    font-size: 16px;
}
header {
    background: #b47941;
    width: 95%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo {
    width: 12%;
    height: 12%;
    float: left;
    background: green;
}
header h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    font: 300% 'Niconne', cursive;
    line-height: 200%;
    height: 0;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 2%;
    background: blue;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
.search {
    display: inline;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <img class="logo" src="https://placehold.it/500x300">
    <h1 class=""> Heading one </h1>
    <input type="search">
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually background color was set successfully, but you can't see because of zero height:

```
header h1 {
  height: 0;
}
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Niconne);

        body{
            background: #e6e3d7;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        header{
            background: #b47941;
            width: 95%;
            padding-left: 1%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .logo{
            width: 12%;
            height: 12%;
            float: left;
            background: green;
        }

        header h1 {
            display: inline-block;
            font:300% 'Niconne', cursive ;
            line-height: 200%;
            color: white;
            margin-left: 2%;
            background: blue;
        }

        .clear{
            clear: both;
        }

        .search{
            display: inline;
            background: blue;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">

        <header>
            <img class="logo" src="https://placehold.it/500x300" >
            <h1 class=""> Heading one </h1>
            <input type="search">
            <div class="clear"></div>

        </header>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

header h1{...`enter code here`...}
remove height:0;

Answer (score 1):

The color you applied to the `img` tag is actually there. It's just directly behind the image, so you can't see it. If you apply `padding: 25px` to the `.logo` class you'll see what I mean.

In terms of the `h1`, you've given it a `height: 0`, so there's no space to show the background color.

Comment: When the image is not floated the text appears below not below the image down on the div do you know why this is happening ?

Comment: Can you provide an image or a clear description of how you want this header to look. Then I'll have a better understanding of your goal.

Answer (score 1):

for your `h1`, the background is not working because you set the height of the element to `0`, so there wouldn't be any color that will show up.

and as for your `img`, the background is not working because you have a image in front of it.

If you want to see the background for the `img`, you can add a padding for it